# How to mock chained promises using Jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I am writing a unit test to a method that contains this piece of code:

```
Name.get($scope.nameId).then(function(name){
    Return name;
}).then(doSomething);
```

The `function doSomething(name)` looks like this.

```
function doSomething(name){
    addNametoList(name);
}
```

I don't need to test this part of the code. Since I can't just ignore it in my test (or can I?), I need to mock it. I mocked the first promise

```
 spyOn(mockName, 'get').and.returnValues($q.resolve({"Mike"}));
```

and thought that it would propagate through the second `then(doSomething)` but `name` is `undefined` in function `addNametoList`.

I think I have to also mock `doSomething` but I have no idea how to chain them together.

Comment: are you not getting an error? The `Return` with an uppercase seems like a typo to me. How did it resolve? Do you return the promise at the end of your jasmine test?

Comment: Yea, I realized that there is some typo in the code. After 2 days of debugging, I finally found out that it was because I didn't set up the object inside $q.resolve() correctly. Other than that, mocking the first promise DOES propagate to the second `.then(doSomething)`. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: It seems that you have a typo - `and.returnValues` ... shouldn't that be `and.returnValue` instead?

**Edit:** Nevermind, sorry, `returnValues` exists in more recent Jasmine versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your (partial) controller code**

```
$scope.list = [];

function addNameToList(name) {
  $scope.list.push(name);
}

function doSomething(name){
  addNametoList(name);
}

$scope.functionToTest = function() {
  Name.get($scope.nameId).then(function(name){
    return name;
  }).then(doSomething);
};
```

**Your test**

```
it('should add the name to the list when Name.get() is resolved', function() {
  // Arrange
  var getDeferred = $q.defer();
  spyOn(mockName, 'get').and.returnValue(getDeferred.promise);

  // Act
  $scope.functionToTest();
  getDeferred.resolve('some name that should be in the list');
  $scope.$apply();

  // Assert
  expect($scope.list).toEqual(['some name that should be in the list']);
});
```

**Comment**

Note that the following part of your code accomplishes nothing, and can be removed without affecting anything.

```
.then(function(name){
  return name;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need to test this part of the code. Since I can't just ignore
>   it in my test (or can I?), I need to mock it. I mocked the first
>   promise

IMO, there is no need to test such setups as a whole.
Test each unit individually.

For example

```
A = () => {
  ...
}

B = () => {
  ...
}

C = () => {
  ...
}
```

Now we have F, which calls A B & C

```
F = () => A(B(C))
```

Or in your case

```
F = () => A().then(B).then(C)
```

We can test F, but it will require some setup, and be fragile.
Its better to test A, B & C (which give at a proper coverage for F) and ignore F.